# How can I animate a scatterplot using the animation package for R?

Tags: r, animation

So far all I have achieved is creating a gif with 30 identical frames, with the last frame having a loess curve.

However, I want an animation that plots each point individually (that is, frame 1 prints the first observation, and frame 2 prints both the first and second observation, etc.). Furthermore, near the end of the animation (once all points and the loess are plotted) I want line segments to be added which connect the points to the loess curve.

I basically want to animate [this plot](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Chapter2/2.2.pdf) from ISLR.

## Code

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide'}
library(animation)

income <- read.csv("Datasets/Income1.csv")

x <- income$Education
y <- income$Income

loess.model <- (loess.smooth(x,y))

saveGIF({
  for(i in 1:30)
    plot(y~x)
  lines(loess.model)
}, interval = 0.15, movie.name = "f.gif", dir(path = "animations"))
```
````

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Only if I include the segments line (segments(x, fitted(loess.model), x, y)). Remove that bit and the code should run.

Comment: Just removed the segment line, should run fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(animation)

x <- cars$speed
y <- cars$dist

l <- loess(y~x)
y_ <- predict(l, newdata = x)

ylim <- range(y)
xlim <- range(x)
p <- function(x,y, ...) 
  plot(x, y, ylim=ylim, xlim=xlim, xlab="x", ylab="y", ...)
times <- c(1, rep(0.1, length(x)), 1, 5) # frame 1 for 1 sec, 2-51 à 0.1 sec, ...

saveGIF({
  p(x,y) # frame 1
  for(i in seq_along(x)) p(x[1:i], y[1:i]) # frames 2-51
  p(x,y);lines(x, y_) # frame 52
  p(x,y);lines(x, y_);segments(x, y_, x, y, col = "red") # frame 53
}, interval = times)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is great!